# zsh doesn't find workon from virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, zsh, virtualenvwrapper

hi i have installed virtualenv python library to manage my env doing all the setup but when i use the following command to open my env that happen

```
francesco@AirdiFrancesco ~ % workon          
zsh: command not found: workon
```

but when i run this code before workon don't give me problems

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
source /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

now i have tried to add this three line to my ~/zshch file but doesn't work. where i need to put this code in my bash?

Comment: It seems like the problem is **specifically** about how to set environment variables, and that it doesn't really matter what they're being used for. Have you tried [unix.se]?

Comment: Does `workon` work after `source virtualenvwrapper.sh`? What exactly doesn't work after adding the 3 commands above to `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: what do you expect `workon` to do? from the standard setup steps, it does not look like you ought to run `workon` but rather `virtualenvwrapper.sh` - make sure that you know which python version you are running and where `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is located

Comment: the folder where `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is  `/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` and my python in `/usr/bin/python3` so what i have to do now

Comment: Please don’t cross-posted your question to multiple SE sites: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733616/issue-with-python-virtualenvwrapper-workon